# Ionic start error file already exists browserslist

Tags: ionic-framework

I have an error since this morning and I didn't find a solution.

I installed Node, npm, Cordova, and Ionic. I go on my folder and try `ionic start`

```
ionic start myproject blank

ionic start myproject blank --type=angular
```

but I always have the same problem.

I tried to uninstall/install/clear npm cache/ add environment path/... but 
nothing.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Though its an old post, but I had the same problem and apparently there is no fix available. What I tried (and worked for me), maybe it will help someone else as well:

- Uninstalled ionic (if already installed)
- Uninstalled node and npm
- Reboot the system

  - This is important, I was trying without rebooting the system and was getting the same error. So restart is a must.
- Re-Install node.js and ionic
- If ionic is not not recognized inside your directory, try somewhere else and if it worked in another directory, simply cleaning the directory should do the trick.

Hope it work for you as well.